# Как объединить два компонента во Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Хочу совместно использовать такие два компонента - [vue-select-image](https://github.com/mazipan/vue-select-image) и [vue-agile](https://github.com/lukaszflorczak/vue-agile). Как сделать так, чтобы каждый элемент vue-select-image оборачивался в один слайд vue-agile.
Массив данных для vue-select-image берётся из json, сейчас при таком коде получается один слайд компонента vue-agile содержит все элементы vue-select-image.

```
<agile :options="sliderOptions">
  <div class="slide">
     <vue-select-image :dataImages="changeTheme" :useLabel=true @onselectimage="onSelectImage">
    </vue-select-image>
  </div>
</agile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать поиграться со слотами. В этой статье(вторая половина) рассматривают что-то подобное.

https://css-live.ru/articles/kak-sozdavat-vue-komponenty-slovno-profi.html

Пример кода из статьи

При комбинировании компонентов со слотами можно передавать данные компонентов в слоты с помощью slot-scope. Можно передавать пропсы вглубь из родительских компонентов в дочерние, не связывая их друг с другом.

```
<template>
  <Settings>
    <Layout slot-scope="{header, body, footer}">
      <Header slot="header" :header="header"></Header>
      <Body slot="body" :body="body"></Body>
      <Footer slot="footer" :footer="footer"></Footer>
    </Layout>
  </Settings>
</template>
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]